# Synonyms in Emacs: thesaurus and synonyms modes

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to use a mode in emacs 24.4.1 for synonyms propositions. I saw those three modes: synonymous, thesaurus and synonyms.

My problems are:

- **synonymous** is apparently not working in emacs without X (i.e. using emacs -nw). The menu is correctly shown using X, but I use emacs in the terminal.
- **thesaurus** is not a fully free solution (you have to use apparently a thesaurus from http://words.bighugelabs.com, which is limited in the number of queries per day through the API)
- [**synonyms**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Synonyms) needs a synonym library at ftp://ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/gutenberg/etext02/mthes10.zip
  which visibly is not available anymore.

How could I obtain a mode for synonyms lookup and replace in Emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see. The url is on ibiblio, but it's in their Gutenberg Project mirror, so I bet we can find it on gutenberg.org. The package docs say that it needs the "Moby Thesaurus II". A quick search and then a little rummaging pulls up the file you need at http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3202/files/mthesaur.txt.

Comment: I was just going to say that googling `"mthes10.zip/"` shows multiple hits. BTW, when you say "the url", you are apparently referring to the thesaurus used by library [Synonyms](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Synonyms)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I just saw your answers now and in the meantime I ended up using another mode that I recommend: **synosaurus** [link](https://github.com/hpdeifel/synosaurus). It's using the freely available wordnet and displaying popups even without X.